# Quel pronom interrogatif ?

Tags: pronoms-interrogatifs

On utilise le verbe " se servir de quelque chose" . Est-ce que c'est correct si je dis : " Tu as plusieurs tasses. De laquelle je peux me servir? La grande ou la petite? "

Comment: Oui, *de laquelle* convient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ne se sert pas de « quelle » dans ce cas : [réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=De+laquelle+je%2CDe+quelle+je&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDe%20laquelle%20je%3B%2Cc0). Il n'y a donc pas de problème du côté du pronom interrogatif.

En ce qui concerne l'ensemble c'est assez correct et beaucoup de monde s'exprimera de cette façon ; cependant vous pouvez aussi dire ceci, qui est irréprochable.

- Tu as plusieurs tasses. De laquelle je peux me servir? De la grande ou de la petite?